# How to test send_file flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a small flask application which takes some images for upload and converts them into a multipage tiff. Nothing special.

But how do I test the upload of multiple files and the file download?

**My Testclient:**

```
class RestTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        rest = imp.load_source('rest', self.dir + '/../rest.py')
        rest.app.config['TESTING'] = True
        self.app = rest.app.test_client()

    def runTest(self):
        with open(self.dir + '/img/img1.jpg', 'rb') as img1:
            img1StringIO = StringIO(img1.read())

        response = self.app.post('/convert',
                                 content_type='multipart/form-data',
                                 data={'photo': (img1StringIO, 'img1.jpg')},
                                 follow_redirects=True)
        assert True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

The application sends back the file with

```
return send_file(result, mimetype='image/tiff', \
                                     as_attachment=True)
```

I want to read the file sent in the response and compare it with another file. How do I get the file from the response object?

Comment: What are the contents of rest.py (or what package is it from), more specifically, what does app.post look like?

Comment: rest.py is my flask application. The convert method, where I post to does some image conversion, and ends with a call to flask.send_file. app.post is a method from flask.test_client.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think maybe the confusion here is that `response` is a [Response](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#flask.Response) object and not the data downloaded by the post request. This is because an HTTP response has other attributes that are often useful to know, for example http status code returned, the mime-type of the response, etc... The attribute names to access these are listed in the link above.

The response object has an attribute called 'data', so `response.data` will contain the data downloaded from the server. The docs I linked to indicate that `data` is soon to be deprecated, and the `get_data()` method should be used instead, but the [testing tutorial](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/testing/#the-first-test) still uses data. Test on your own system to see what works.Assuming you want to test a round trip of the data,

```
def runTest(self):
    with open(self.dir + '/img/img1.jpg', 'rb') as img1:
        img1StringIO = StringIO(img1.read())

    response = self.app.post('/convert',
                             content_type='multipart/form-data',
                             data={'photo': (img1StringIO, 'img1.jpg')},
                             follow_redirects=True)
    img1StringIO.seek(0)
    assert response.data == imgStringIO.read()
```

Comment: With Python 3, you should use `BytesIO` instead of `StringIO` here since `img1` is read in binary mode due to `mode='rb'`.