# Mocking download of a file using Python requests and responses

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-requests

I have some python code which successfully downloads an image from a URL, using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), and saves it into `/tmp/`. I want to test this does what it should. I'm using [responses](https://github.com/getsentry/responses) to test fetching of JSON files, but I'm not sure how to mock the behaviour of fetching a file.

I assume it'd be similar to mocking a standard response, like the below, but I think I'm blanking on how to set the `body` to be a file...

```
@responses.activate
def test_download():
    responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://example.org/images/my_image.jpg',
              body='', status=200,
              content_type='image/jpeg')
    #...
```

**UPDATE:** Following Ashafix's comment, I'm trying this (python 3):

```
from io import BytesIO

@responses.activate
def test_download():
    with open('tests/images/tester.jpg', 'rb') as img1:
        imgIO = BytesIO(img1.read())

    responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://example.org/images/my_image.jpg',
              body=imgIO, status=200,
              content_type='image/jpeg')
    imgIO.seek(0)
    #...
```

But when, subsequently, the code I'm testing attempts to do the request I get:

```
a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BytesIO'
```

Feels like it's almost right, but I'm stumped.

**UPDATE 2:** Trying to follow Steve Jessop's suggestion:

```
@responses.activate
def test_download():
    with open('tests/images/tester.jpg', 'rb') as img1:
        responses.add(responses.GET, 'http://example.org/images/my_image.jpg',
                  body=img1.read(), status=200,
                  content_type='image/jpeg')
        #...
```

But this time the code being tested raises this:

```
I/O operation on closed file.
```

Surely the image should still be open inside the `with` block?

**UPDATE 3:** The code I'm testing is something like this:

```
r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
if r.status_code == 200:
     with open('/tmp/temp.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        r.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
```

It seems to be that the final `shutil` line is generating the "I/O operation on closed file." error. I don't understand this enough - the streaming of the file - to know how best to mock this behaviour, to test the downloaded file is saved to `/tmp/`.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26364642/2776376

Comment: Does `body = open(filename, 'rb').read()` not work? In practice as with any call to `open`, you might want to use it as a context manager.

Comment: Thanks both... I've inched forward with both suggestions, but not quite there yet!

Comment: Have you tried not using a with block and simply using `img1 = open(...)` and then `img1.close()` afterwards?

Comment: Thanks Sepehr. I'm still getting "I/O operation on closed file", even though I'm only closing it after calling the code I'm testing. Weird! Might it be to do with using `stream` with requests? I'm doing `r = requests.get(url, stream=True)`

Comment: It's the code that's saving the downloaded file that's generating the error. i've added another update.

Answer (score 8):

You might need to pass `stream=True` to the `responses.add` call. Something like:

```
@responses.activate
def test_download():
    with open("tests/images/tester.jpg", "rb") as img1:
        responses.add(
            responses.GET,
            "http://example.org/images/my_image.jpg",
            body=img1.read(),
            status=200,
            content_type="image/jpeg",
            stream=True,
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

First, to summarise my now overly long question... I'm testing some code that's something like:

```
def download_file(url):
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
         filename = os.path.basename(url)
         with open('/tmp/%s' % filename, 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
         return filename
```

It downloads an image and, streaming it, saves it to `/tmp/`. I wanted to mock the request so I can test other things.

```
@responses.activate
def test_downloads_file(self):
    url = 'http://example.org/test.jpg'
    with open('tests/images/tester.jpg', 'rb') as img:
        responses.add(responses.GET, url,
                        body=img.read(), status=200,
                        content_type='image/jpg',
                        adding_headers={'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'})
        filename = download_file(url)
        # assert things here.
```

Once I had worked out the way to use `open()` for this, I was still getting "I/O operation on closed file." from `shutil.copyfileobj()`. The thing that's stopped this is to add in the `Transfer-Encoding` header, which is present in the headers when I make the real request.

Any suggestions for other, better solutions very welcome!

Comment: This worked for a bit, and now no longer works; I still get `I/O operation on closed file.`

Comment: Looks like something changed with `requests` v2.12.0 which has resulted in this. The test works fine when v2.11.1 is installed, but not with v2.12.0-v2.13.0.